# Different results from the same function (numpy, OCR)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ocr, captcha

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I am wrtiting a program with Python 3.4.1 to analyze a certain type of captcha.
Here's the part where I have the problem.

```
def f(path):
    i = Image.open(path)
    a = np.array(i) #to transform the image into an array using numpy
    b = combinator(a) #this is a function I created to process the image (thresholding...)
    capreader(b) #this is a function that divides the array and recognizes the character in each segment (I created previously functions for each character)
```

now when I call f() for a path 'p' it gives me a certain result (which is wrong). And when I call each of the instructions inside f() individually it gives me an other result (which is correct):

```
i = Image.open('p')
ia = np.array(i)
ib = combinator(ia)
capreader(ib)
```

This is weird! because I think that logically they should give the same result.
I then tried to see if inside f(), the array b is the same if it isn't inside f():

```
def x(path):
    i = Image.open(path)
    a = np.array(i)
    b = combinator(a)
    print(np.array_equal(b,ib)
```

and the result was False.
I then tested this:

```
def y(path):
    i = Image.open(path)
    a = np.array(i)
    b = combinator(a)
    plt.imshow(b)
    plt.show()
    capreader(b)
```

this time (after I close the pyplot window) capreader() gives me the correct answer!!
so I continued the testing, this time with this:

```
def test(path):
    a = Image.open(path)
    b = np.array(a)
    c = combinator(b)
    print(np.array_equal(c,ib)) #False
    plt.imshow(c)
    plt.show()
    print(np.array_equal(c,ib)) #True
    capreader(c)
```

I don't understand what's happening and how I can solve it. obviously what's making the difference here are the function from plt between the two comparisons which give opposing results(False, True). I read on the internet that plt.show() is a blocking function. I don't know what that means, but I put it in here in case it helps solving the case.

Comment: In the function `x` you call `b = combinator(b)`. Typo or error?

Comment: In `test` please check `max(c)` before **and** after `plt.imshow(c)`. From the docs of `imshow`: *MxN float arrays may be normalised.*.

Comment: `imshow` normalizes internally, mpl should not be mutating user input.

Comment: @a_guest it is not a typo, and it is not an error. i update the variable b. it doesn't matter if we do it like this: z = combinator(b)

Comment: @a_guest i tried that and it gives me an ValueError: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @tcaswell Actually what I want is to get the result I get from capreader() after plt.show(). Also I think that what does the change is the show() function. I read on the internet that it's a blocking function. I don't understand that, but now to finish the program (not in a pefect way. i just need it to work) i just need to know how to close the pyplot window. i could also replace the imshow() and show() with any other blocking function(if the blocking is what makes this work) to get the correct array. I hope this is understandable. Thanks guys

Comment: @pyvis It must be a typo because the variable `b` does not exist at this line of code. Thus the program should raise a `NameError`. And are you sure that you tried `max(c)`? Because this has nothing to do with truth values. Looks like you tried `bool(c)`.

Comment: @a_guest that was a typo (here, but in my computer it was well written. so the problem is still there). i tried max(c) and not bool(c). thanks again for the answer.